# How do I add a new content type entry link at drupal top page?

Tags: drupal-7

I am creating a Drupal-7.12 test site.
After adding a new content type "famous airplane", how do I add a "famous airplane entry" link similar to "Blog entry" link under "Add content" menu at our user loginned top page?

Own Answer:

Home » Administration » People >> Permissions TAB

Node

- famous airplane: Create new content
- famous airplane: Edit own content
- famous airplane: Edit any content
- famous airplane: Delete own content
- famous airplane: Delete any content

Check above for authenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the normal user to add content, then you need to set the permission. Under People > Permission you will find node. And there you have to add the permission so that users can add content. But yes, giving permission to users who add content directly has a lot of security implications.

So act accordingly. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your collect answer. I also find out the solution and add my own answer into my question article because my stackoverflow account created just today so I could not post a new answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully created the content type then the link will come automatically under node/add link. But I am not sure if you mean the top black toolbar or somewhere else.

If you need to add the link at the top of the toolbar then go to the create content and then to your famous airplane add content form, there at the top you will see a black plus icon which will help you add the link at the top in the black toolbar also know as shortcut bar.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Administrator could add "famous airplane". I mean a user could not see any links for creating a new content "famous airplane". What should I do for our new users?